# Rails: How to enable permenant session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have a rails app running on version: 5.2.1
My app is not keeping persistent session and users need to re-login frequently (few times a week).

I would like to keep user sessions forever (or at least for few years) until the user signout by herself.

I haven't changed any parameters regarding to session period so I assume it is on default settings. Here I will appreciate if you can guide me how to change session period on my app.

I use devise for login, and here is the User Model configuration:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :admin_user, :auth_login
  has_ancestry

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable
```

Comment: What do you use for login? Devise?

Comment: Yes, I use devise and updated the question to highlight it.

Comment: could you show the line where you configure devise in the model (starting with `devise)`

Comment: I have added devise related config in the User Model

Comment: @Tolga did you solve the issue? If the answer helped you please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the modules listed in the comment above the devise configurations in the User model. You can use those modules without using an extra gem. Uncomment the `:timeoutable` module and set the desired timeout in devise.rb :

```
# ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
# The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
# time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
config.timeout_in = 3.years
```